# How can I set a schema.Datetime field to None with Dexterity

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm writing a simple content type with Dexterity to manage customers, beside the usuals fields, eg name, company, phone... 
I've also added a Datetime field to store when the first meeting with 
customers has  been held, lets call it 'firstmeeting', which I defined 
in my interface ICustomers as:

```
firstmeeting = schema.Datetime(
        title=_(u"First Meeting"),
        required=False,
    )
```

Now, I notice that when I saved a new Customer document the firstmeeting
field has been filled with the current date even if I don't set any date 
in the form, which is not what I want because no meeting with the
customer has been held yet. So I'd  like to know how to set a None value 
for this field so nothing will be displayed.

I've been trying to use a custom class has explained by Martin Aspeli in
http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/classes
but I don't know how to check the user input and set None value if nothing
was typed in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening in my code.

Actually the problem was in the template view.pt where I used toLocalizedTime() function,
which was converting the None value to the current date, so I added a tal:condition to print the date value.

```
<span id="form-widgets-firstmeeting" class="datetime-widget datetime-field"
      tal:condition="context/firstmeeting"
      tal:content="python:context.toLocalizedTime(context.firstmeeting)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `default=None`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but didn't work. The problem here isn't to set a default value for the user, which is already None. The problem is that when the user save the form something happen that change the field value from None to the current date.